# unable to read file using getResourceAsStream

Tags: java

I have a folder structure like
Project

- src
- --TestMain.java
- bin
- --TestMain.class
- resources
- --test.txt

As the whole project will be packaged into a jar file, I have to read a file from resources using getResourceAsStream. Although I have read through all questions about getResourceAsStream, I still can't get this working. Could anyone help? Thank you!

```
public class TestMain {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

InputStream stream = TestMain.class.getResourceAsStream("\resources\test.txt");
    System.out.println(stream);
    BufferedReader bufRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    String line=null;
    while((line=bufRead.readLine())!=null){
        builder.append(line).append("\n");
    }
    System.out.println(builder.toString());

}
}
```

Comment: are you getting null pointer exception? or anything

Comment: Yes, I do. I got null pointer of the InputStream: stream.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically, there are 2 different methods: `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()` and `Class.getResourceAsStream()`. These two methods will locate the resource differently.

In `Class.getResourceAsStream(path)`, the path is interpreted as a path local to the package of the class you are calling it from. For example calling, `String.getResourceAsStream("file.txt")` will look for a file in your classpath at the following location: `"java/lang/file.txt"`. If your path starts with a `/`, then it will be considered an absolute path, and will start searching from the root of the classpath. So calling `String.getResourceAsStream("/myfile.txt")` will look at the following location in your class path ./file.txt.

`ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(path)` will consider all paths to be absolute paths. So calling `String.getClassLoader().getResourceAsString("myfile.txt")` and `String.getClassLoader().getResourceAsString("/file.txt")` will both look for a file in your classpath at the following location: `./file.txt`.

Every time the location, it could be a location in your filesystem itself, or inside the corresponding jar file, depending on the Class and/or ClassLoader you are loading the resource from.

IF  you are loading the class from an Application Server, so your should use `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName)` instead of `this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName)`. `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream()` will also work.

Comment: Thank you for sharing - much appreciated! Does it mean we should always use ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream() instead of Class?getResourceAsStream()?

Comment: Copy paste this much? [Different ways of loading a file as an InputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/676273/1041046)

Answer (score 1):

It seems the folder 'resources' is in your classpath, it is not need while getting resources under it,try below

```
InputStream stream = TestMain.class.getResourceAsStream("test.txt");
```

Comment: I am sure that I added the resources folder into my runtime classpath. However, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Is your test.txt in your classpath? I think that your test.txt is not inside your classpath. 
you have many solutions for to do that.

- one could be give the fullpath of your file (c:/......)
- verify  when you generate .jar file your txt is inside .jar. if not include your resource folder inside your java project. when you include made a path directly for 
  getResourceAsStream ("test.txt")

For disacoplated resource of your  java project use a first option but if it not make sense use the second option .

Comment: When I generate .jar file, it seems the resources folder is not there. How do I include the resources folder in the .jar file? May I ask how to made a path directly to "text.txt" just in case I didn't do it right? I use Eclipse. Thank you.

Comment: well .... Rick click in your project/Build Path/ New source folder . Then paste your test.txt

Comment: but i think if your run: mvn clean package he must generate a jar with the resource.  If you use maven look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17617964/why-is-the-maven-jar-plugin-not-including-some-resources.     you could read a cookbook about maven jar plugin too. good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you are using a httpclient:

```
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

        httpClient.getHostConfiguration().setProxy(proxyHost, proxyPort);//your proxyHost & your proxyPort,

        GetMethod getMethod = new GetMethod(url);//your url,

        try {
            httpClient.executeMethod(getMethod);
            //strData = getMethod.getResponseBodyAsString();

            InputStream resStream = getMethod.getResponseBodyAsStream();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(resStream));
            StringBuffer resBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            String resTemp = "";
            while((resTemp = br.readLine()) != null){
                resBuffer.append(resTemp);
            }
            String response = resBuffer.toString();             
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("HttpProxyManager.getResponse returns NULL");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            getMethod.releaseConnection();
        }
```

the string response should be what you want to get.